# How do I get a token from Django AllAuth SocialAccount?

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, django-allauth

I'm trying to get a user account and tokens for Google Calendars as such:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

    ...

    account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user) 
    token = account.socialtoken_set.all().order_by('-expires_at').first()

    creds.expiry = timezone.make_naive(token.expires_at)

    creds = Credentials(
        token=token.token,
        refresh_token=token.token_secret,
```

However, when I try running the site I get "SocialAccount matching query does not exist." in response to the `account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)`  line. What is the correct way for me to get the account?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, for some reason it did not work with the Gmail account associated with my admin account. Using a different gmail account worked.